# How can I use a react component in a function?

Tags: reactjs

I have this code, inside of my code I am using a component, this should be possible?

```
let newBox = document.createElement("span")
for (let a = 0; a < suggestions.length; a++) {
 let newDiv= <Option value={suggestions[a]}/>
 newBox.appendChild(newDiv)
}

item.appendChild(newBox)
```

This component  its only this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Option = (value) => {
    return (<div className="divBorder"> {value} </div>)
}

export default Option
```

Btw: I have this error in this part:`newBox.appendChild(newDiv)`

This is the error:

```
TypeError: Node.appendChild: Argument 1 does not implement interface Node.
```

Comment: Direct DOM manipulations in React are generally anti-pattern. What and where is the first code running? Is that code running in a React app? No, you can't just append an uninstantiated React component JSX literal to vanilla HTML.

Comment: It doesn't appear you are even using React, just append a `div` element and set the `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to understand how React’s JSX and “virtual DOM” work.

Things like `<Option value={suggestions[a]} />` written in JSX, is eventually transpiled to JS, and the equivalent result is

```js
React.createElement(Option, { value: suggestions[a] }, null)
```

Now you should see it’s impossible to append such a thing directly into DOM, it’s not even a valid DOM element!

It’s a React element, aka virtual DOM element, it’s meant to be consumed by a renderer engine that understands how to make sense of it. `react-dom` lib is the engine for web platform, there can be other engine.

Answer (score 1):

incase you want to embed your react component array to that span you can use something like this

1. render sub-dom-tree inside an elemnent

```
const newBox = document.createElement("span")

const embed = () => {
  const itemsArray = []
   for (let a = 0; a < suggestions.length; a++) {          
     itemsArray.push(<Option value={suggestions[a]}/>)
  }

  ReactDOM.render(itemsArray, newBox)
}
```

> This was how old packages like hot-reload watched you component changes and re-fresh browser for changes.

But here is a react-ish way if you want

```
const NewBox = () => (
  <span>
   {suggestions.map(value => (
     <Option value={value} />
   ))}
  </span>
)


const Option = props => 
  <div className="divBorder"> {JSON.stringify(props)} </div>
```